# How do I add extra/custom plugins in CKEditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

- I am copying the templates plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/templates
- I put    it in my D8 folder /core/asstes/vendor/ckeditor/plugins
- I do a 'drush    cr'

I do not see the templates plugin under available buttons in my text format

How do I get the templates plugin to show up?

Comment: While this worked in D7, for D8 I think you have to create a custom module.

Comment: take a look at the 2nd last comment here https://www.drupal.org/node/2618278

Answer (score 2):

You have to build a plugin in Drupal using the CKEditor classes in the CKEditor module in core, it is not an automatic integration.

Check some of the existing modules that integrate plugins for examples on how to do this.

Checkout:

- [CodeSnippet](https://www.drupal.org/project/codesnippet)
- [Color Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton)
- [Panel Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelbutton)

Comment: Slow progress.  Noticing that the ckeditor_font module together with the font add-on from ckeditor.com works so well,  I created a ckeditor_templates based on the ckeditor_font module, module and put the Content Templates add-on from ckeditor into d8site/library/  This works! I can see the templates when creating content.  But when I remove or add new templates to the D8site/library/templates/templates/default.js,  I do NOT see my changes.

Comment: the templates add-on was placed in the d8site/libraries folder

Comment: I have noticed that there is a particular quirk with caching of CKEditor plugins where clearing Drupal cache or cache-rebuild does not get new changes to plugin js. I verified by comparing my source in my browser to the JS file, even with aggregation off. Try seeing if your updated plugin code is in the JS file the browser sees.

Comment: FYI - Got it working!!!!  In the file d8site/lbraries/templates/plugin.js on line 81, I changed the path to point to '/libraries/templates/templates/default.js'  and that made use my templates file.

Comment: Hm, not familiar with why the CKEditor plugin would need modification, but welcome to the quick world of plugin integration. Contribute back on d.o. If it is useful.

Comment: The content of d8sites/libraries/ckeditor should be managed with drush/drupal commands that CKEditor exposes to you (each library is mapped with a module that command with it's own commands). CKEditor has its versioning, Drupal CKEditor module has its versioning, and each CKEditor plugin has its versioning. Thats why you can not work with raw CKEditor and should follow integration Drupal guidance for each plugin.